# How to call a function from another controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

I need to call a function in another controller in AngularJS. How can I do this?

Code:

```
app.controller('One', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.parentmethod = function() {
            // task
        }
    }
]);

app.controller('two', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.childmethod = function() {
            // Here i want to call parentmethod of One controller
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Put the function in a service, and inject the service in both controllers. Or, if the second controller scope is a child of the first controller scope, call it directly.

Comment: This feels like an XY Question to me; While there are a few ways you *can* call a function on another controller, there are really very few good reasons that you *have* to do so.  Perhaps describing what your actual problem is would be more helpful than asking about the solution you are trying to implement?  Calling a function on a different controller isn't really the "angular way" of doing things.

Comment: is one controller a child/grand-child of the other controller? Or are they unrelated siblings?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Communication between controllers is done though `$emit` + `$on` / `$broadcast` + `$on` methods.

So in your case you want to call a method of Controller "One" inside Controller "Two", the correct way to do this is:

```
app.controller('One', ['$scope', '$rootScope'
    function($scope) {
        $rootScope.$on("CallParentMethod", function(){
           $scope.parentmethod();
        });

        $scope.parentmethod = function() {
            // task
        }
    }
]);
app.controller('two', ['$scope', '$rootScope'
    function($scope) {
        $scope.childmethod = function() {
            $rootScope.$emit("CallParentMethod", {});
        }
    }
]);
```

While `$rootScope.$emit` is called, you can send any data as second parameter.

Comment: I am able to call the function just using $rootScope.function_name();

Comment: with a minor issue for param passing.. this resolved a big issue of mine. Thanks

Comment: we can not pass parameter like this. 1st param is event whereas 2nd is data. like $rootScope.$on("CallParentMethod", function(event,data){{});

Answer (score 28):

I wouldn't use function from one controller into another. A better approach would be to move the common function to a service and then inject the service in both controllers.

Comment: This is not always possible

Answer (score 10):

You may use events to provide your data. Code like that:

```
app.controller('One', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
         $scope.parentmethod=function(){
                 $scope.$emit('one', res);// res - your data
         }
    }]);
    app.controller('two', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
         $scope.$on('updateMiniBasket', function (event, data) {
                ...
         });             
    }]);
```

Comment: Life saver. There is an answer above , I followed it and it almost worked for me but param was not received. He missed the point that if we want to pass param, we need to do $scope.$on('someMehotdName',function(event,data){});

Answer (score 7):

If the `two` controller is ***nested*** in `One` controller.
Then you can simply call:

```
$scope.parentmethod();
```

Angular will **search** for `parentmethod` function starting with current scope and up until it will reach the `rootScope`.

Answer (score 5):

The best approach for you to communicate between the two controllers is to use events.

See the [scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) documentation

In this check out `$on`, `$broadcast` and `$emit`.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to execute the parent controller's parentmethod function inside a child controller, call it:

```
$scope.$parent.parentmethod();
```

You can try it over [here](http://codepen.io/ER144/pen/YPbpWo)