# call a method and send value from controller1 to controller2 in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

based on this reply [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467339/how-to-call-function-in-another-controller-in-angularjs) I tried to send a data when I click on a button and call a method from Controller1 to Controller2
this is my try:

Controller1:

```
$scope.DetailsLivraison = function(){                                       
                var idv = $scope.idBonSortie;
       $rootScope.$emit("CallParentMethod", idv);                                                                                                  
}
```

Controller2:

```
$rootScope.$on("CallParentMethod", function(){
                   $scope.parentmethod(idv);
                });

$scope.parentmethod = function(idv) {
 //Data traitment
}
```

my problem is that,the method in the second controller is not called,I have defined $rootscope in both controllers
any help please to solve the problem
thanks for help

Comment: Are your both controllers on the same view ?

Comment: no MiTa they are not on the same view :)

Comment: So it's not possible to do it with events, controller will listen only if it's active - it's assigned to a page element.

Comment: ok thanks MiTa,in this case should I use a service to share Data between those two controllers??

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly, to make this happen both your controllers should be active at that time.**

Secondly, you can use the code below:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('CallParentMethod', { //can also use $emit
    idv: idv,
});
```

At the receiving end in the other controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('CallParentMethod', function(event, args) {

       $scope.parentmethod(args.idv);

});
```

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,I tried your code but still not working,the method in the second controller is not called :(

Comment: Is the second controller active at that time?

Comment: how do I know if it's active or not??in my app each view has a controller,I try with Controller1 to display view2 by calling a method in its controller2 Sir

Comment: you can check if both the controllers are active at the same time by doing console.log("active") in both controllers. As they load you should see two console.log statements in browser console

Comment: No Sir,they are not activated at the same time,in this case should I use a service to share Data between those two controllers??