# share data between two Views in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 views,each one has a controller,I want to send data from View1 to View2 when I click on the "BL" Button:

this is View1:
[image]

and this is View2:
[image]

I tried to use the events [my try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555429/call-a-method-and-send-value-from-controller1-to-controller2-in-angularjs/38555595?noredirect=1#comment64502594_38555595),but the Controller2 will be activated only when I click on the "BL" Button
I thought to use a service to send Data from controller1 to controller2,but I think it's not my case
so please is there any help,how can I send data from View1 to View2
thanks

Edit:
this is my second try:

View1/controller1:

```
 $scope.BLButton = function(){


    $scope.foo = Service.foo;
    Service.foo = '85';

    }
    .factory('Service', function() {
                                  var Service = {
                                        foo: '85'
                                      };
                                      return Service;
                                    });
```

View2/Controller2:

```
//this method is called to display the data in the input Text from a web Service
$scope.parentmethod = function() {
  //traitement
$scope.foo = Service.foo;
....
}
```

the problem with my code is that the method "parentmethod" of Controleller2 is never called when I click on the "BL" button

Comment: There are couple of ways to achieve this (shared service, components). Post your code for better help.

Comment: First thing you generally want to look at is using a service to share data across parts of  the app. Your image is of little value, please provide [mcve]

Comment: I have updated my post Sir

Comment: Wait, I'm all confused. I don't think you can attach a factory to a scope function, unless this is some syntax I'm not aware of.

Comment: I have called the name of Factory in both Controllers Sir

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to move all you business logic (BL) to a service which will maintain app state. You're trying to misuse controllers in a way, because their only goal is to glue presentation and BL and not to hold app state in any form. The problem is that controllers are created and destroyed on view change, so they don't fit as state holders. In your case you can store data in a service (which is instantiated and alive all the time your app works) and then retrieve it in another view in controller.