# Calling function in child controller from parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have a controller nested in another controller.

```
<div ng-controller="manufacturerController" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="contractController" ng-cloak>
        <div data-ng-if="item" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                <span class="h3">Contract</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button data-ng-if="item && !ajaxOut" class="btn btn-success" data-ng-click="saveItem()">Save</button>
</div>
```

saveItem() is called via the button and the code is in the manufacturerController:

```
    $scope.saveItem = function () {
        $scope.ajaxOut = true;
        $scope.saveContracts();
    };
```

But the function saveContracts() is in the contractController. I want to call the contractController.saveContracts() from manufacturerController.saveItem().

According to here I should be able to call the parent method fine: [How to call a function from another controller in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467339/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-controller-in-angularjs)

But the save is freezing the browser. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: You don't do this directly. You do it via an event/notification. Controllers should have no knowledge of each other. You can either use the built in $broadcast, or you can just set up a simple observer-notification service.

Comment: @TimConsolazio Can you provide an example?

Comment: Look up "$on $emit $broadcast angularjs". Tons and tons of examples out there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can one controller call another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is broadcasting an event on scope:

```
function ParentController($scope) 
{
  $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', args);
}

function ChildController($scope) 
{
  $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, args) {});
  // another controller or even directive
}
```

> ## Scope Events Propagation
>
> Scopes can propagate events in similar fashion to DOM events. The event can be [broadcasted](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) to the scope children or [emitted](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) to scope parents.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Event Propagation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation)

For more information, see [Can one controller call another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another)

Answer (score 1):

You can use $broadcast from the parent to a child:

```
function ParentCntl($scope) {

    $scope.msg = "";
    $scope.get = function(){
        $scope.$broadcast ('someEvent');
        return  $scope.msg;        
    }
}

function ChildCntl($scope) {               
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function(e) {  
        $scope.$parent.msg = $scope.get();            
    });

    $scope.get = function(){
        return "xyz";    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look up "$on $emit $broadcast angularjs". Tons and tons of examples out there.

(As I said previously in my comment, you don't want controllers to have any knowledge of each other. One dispatches an event/notification, another hears it, sort of like somebody you don't know just standing up in a room and shouting a name you're interested in).

Each is used for a different context. Depending on what you're doing, you might use one or the other. Understanding each of those is super important to the AngularJS developer (and the overall concept to any UI dev).