# Pushing an Object from one controller to another in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am having problems trying to push an object from one controller to an array in another controller. Can anyone help me with that? I am looking into Angular $broadcast and $emit but I'm not sure on how to approach it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function from another controller in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467339/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-controller-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use services for sharing data between controllers. It is better than sending messages.
Btw to use $broadcast and $emit you can do the following.

Inside the controller which broadcast the event:

```
$scope.broadcastEvent = function() {
    $scope.$broadcast('my-broadcast', myElement);
};
```

Inside the other controller:

```
$scope.$on('my-broadcast', function(event, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

To decide between $broadcast or $emit you have to see your structure of controllers. 
Otherwise instead of sending the $broadcast from $scope, you can start the broadcast from $rootScope, and it will be detected everytime.

But again, **you do use services for sharing data in these cases**

Comment: Thank you, very useful info