# function not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
.controller("selectStudentController",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.showStudents = function(){
        $http.post("selectStudent.php").then(function(response){
            $scope.studentData = response.data;
        })
    }
})
.controller("saveStudentController",function($scope,$http){
    $scope.saveIt = function(){
        $http.post("saveNewStudent.php", {"sName" : $scope.sName,
                                          "gender" : $scope.gender,
                                          "salary" : $scope.salary,
                                          "dob" : $scope.dob}
        ).then(function(response){                            
            alert("Record Saved Successfully...");  
            $scope.showStudents();                            
        })                        
    }                   
})
```

Hi, this is my code. Here, when i call `$scope.showStudents();` is not working after **Record Saved Successfully...** message. Can anybody tell me what is the mistake in it. My record saved and select fine but i unable to call this function.

Comment: you are doing wrong / your mistakes are: using `$scope`, putting obsolete quotes around object property names, using `alert` for debugging and having all controllers chained in one file. But the biggest mistake is asking question on stackoverflow before you understand your own code and calling it `function not working` which is describing 99% of programming problems

Comment: Any console error ??

Comment: why are you chaining the controllers? can you create a separate controller  with different variables? like var app = angular.module([]); then  app.controller("selectStudentController") and app.controller("saveStudentController")

Comment: can you post the HTML also?

Comment: everything is working fine... only $scope.showStudents() is not working after inserting the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not called directly local `scope` method in different `controller`

You have following way to access the methods in controller,

1. Create same method in same controller
2. Use services and inject in controller
3. Use $rootScope(But not good idea)
4. Use `$broadcast` and `$emit`

Sample code for you,

```
 .controller("saveStudentController",function($scope,$http){
                          //here declare your method
                          $scope.showStudents = function(){
                              $http.post(
                                  "selectStudent.php"
                                  ).then(function(response){
                                      $scope.studentData = response.data;
                                  })
                             }
                             $scope.saveIt = function(){
                                  $http.post("saveNewStudent.php",
                                  {"sName":$scope.sName,
                                  "gender" : $scope.gender,
                                  "salary" : $scope.salary,
                                  "dob" : $scope.dob
                                  }                                                                
                              ).then(function(response){                            
                                  alert("Record Saved Successfully...");  
                                  $scope.showStudents();                            
                              })                        
                          }                   
                      })
```

Please check same question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This question already has an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467339/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-controller-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 controllers `selectStudentController` and `saveStudentController`

Suppose  `selectStudentController` is not a **parent scope** of `saveStudentController` (otherwise your code should work)

You cannot call directly method of other controller from local one.

The best practice is to use `service`. Put method `showStudents` logic into service that will be available from both controllers.

```
app.service('YourService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var self = this;

    self.showStudents = function(){
        return $http.post(
             "selectStudent.php"
          ).then(function(response){
               return response.data;
          })
       }    
  }]);
```

And now `saveStudentController` will look like:

```
.controller("saveStudentController",function($rootScope, $scope,$http,YourService){
                   $scope.saveIt = function(){
                        $http.post("saveNewStudent.php",
                        {"sName":$scope.sName,
                        "gender" : $scope.gender,
                        "salary" : $scope.salary,
                        "dob" : $scope.dob
                        }                                                                
                    ).then(function(response){                            
                        alert("Record Saved Successfully...");  
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('showStudents', {});
                    })                        
                }                   
            })
```

`selectStudentController` controller:

```
 .controller("selectStudentController",function($scope,YourService){

    $scope.$on("showStudents", function (event, data) {                    
      YourService.showStudents().then(function(response){
           $scope.studentData = response.data;
       })      
    });
  })
```

---

`saveIt` method you can also put into Service

Comment: thanks it is working fine. I don't know this.  Recently i started to work on angularjs. but thanks once again i got new idea to create and call service.